# IE Compatibility View changes overflow values

Tags: jquery, overflow

This is my first post.

I have an application which is loading an included file

```
    <div id="formChangeResult" class="innerWhiteContainer ">
      <jsp:include page="queryJSP/nameChangedDepot.jsp">
      </jsp:include>    
    </div><!-- end formChangeResult -->
```

And nameChangedDepot.jsp contains a table with a result set from a database query.  There is a class "scroll" on the table which tells jQuery that the table is fitting inside the  (above) and is to be scrolling.

This works ideally when the user's browser has Compatibility View enabled for this app.  The table is placed within another  (within *formChangeResult*) which has "overflow-y:auto, overflow-x:auto".

My problem is when a user does not have Compatibility View enabled for the app, the overflow value for the div is "overflow:hidden".

My need is to either find a way to remove this "change" when coming out of compatibility view or be able to force compatibility view for this app.

I have tried varying jQuery versions, from 1.2.6 to 1.7.1 and all of the ones I've tried behave the same.  I've tried IE8 v. IE9, both behave the same.  The only thing that seems to make a difference is turning compatibility view on.  It's an easy enough work-around, but I can't rely on user-compliance just to use my app.

Thanks.

Comment: IE compatibility view should only be used in rare circumstances when page layout is specially designed for older browsers. Tell your users they shouldn't be using it at all.

Comment: I agree, Blazemonger.  I'd rather have it a complete non-factor.  But the app doesn't work without it.  They HAVE to use the app - a required tool.  So compatibility view is the only way to get their work done.